# getting permutations without repeat when its unnecessary

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, permutation

How can get all permutations of elements in nested list without repeating when it's unnecessary.
So for example if I have a nested list:

```
[['a1','a2','a3'], ['b1', 'b2'], ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4']]
```

I want to get:

```
['a1', 'b1', 'c1']
['a2', 'b2', 'c2']
['a3', 'b1', 'c3']
['a1', 'b2', 'c4']
```

Comment: What do you mean by `without repeating when it's unnecessary`. Here your output is incomplete, it misses many permutations. [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) are for sure a good place to start for this kind of problem.

Comment: What you want isn't permutations, it's a cross product.

Comment: He's asking for each column to cycle through their respective values, aka 1/2/3/1/2/3, 1/2/1/2/1/2, 1/2/3/4/1/2 for a, b, c respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and [`itertools.cycle()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle):

```
from itertools import cycle

src = [['a1','a2','a3'], ['b1', 'b2'], ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4']]
res = list(zip(*map(lambda x, m=max(src): cycle(x) if x != m else x, src)))
```

---

Using [`max()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) we find element with maximum length and [apply](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) `cycle()` to all elements of the list except this one (*with max length*). Then we [unpack](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) results into `zip()` and get what you need.

If you want to print result in exact format from question, use next code:

```
print(*map(list, zip(*map(lambda x, m=max(src): cycle(x) if x != m else x, src))), sep="\n")
```

Comment: yeah, that's it. i did the same but was using itertools.product(. my fault

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are searching is what you wrote, `itertools.product`

```py
itertools.product((*[['a1','a2','a3'], ['b1', 'b2'], ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4']])) # ->

"""
[('a1', 'b1', 'c1'),
 ('a1', 'b1', 'c2'),
 ('a1', 'b1', 'c3'),
 ('a1', 'b1', 'c4'),
 ('a1', 'b2', 'c1'),
 ('a1', 'b2', 'c2'),
 ('a1', 'b2', 'c3'),
 ('a1', 'b2', 'c4'),
 ('a2', 'b1', 'c1'),
 ('a2', 'b1', 'c2'),
 ('a2', 'b1', 'c3'),
 ('a2', 'b1', 'c4'),
 ('a2', 'b2', 'c1'),
 ('a2', 'b2', 'c2'),
 ('a2', 'b2', 'c3'),
 ('a2', 'b2', 'c4'),
 ('a3', 'b1', 'c1'),
 ('a3', 'b1', 'c2'),
 ('a3', 'b1', 'c3'),
 ('a3', 'b1', 'c4'),
 ('a3', 'b2', 'c1'),
 ('a3', 'b2', 'c2'),
 ('a3', 'b2', 'c3'),
 ('a3', 'b2', 'c4')]
"""
```

Comment: ['a1', 'b1', 'c1']
['a2', 'b2', 'c2']
['a3', 'b1', 'c3']
['a1', 'b2', 'c4'] is a desired result. I want to use each element in sublist just once, but if sublists have different length than i can use it again, but if its not necessary than i don't want to use it

Comment: @EdZ you ask for all the premutations without repeats, which is this list

Comment: No, he doesn't. He asks for each column to cycle through their respective values, aka 1/2/3/1/2/3, 1/2/1/2/1/2, 1/2/3/4/1/2 for a, b, c respectively.

Comment: @Corsaka exactly

Comment: @EdZ oh ok, edit your question so it will be more clear :)